# Backbone - Checkbox stays checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js, dom-events

I'm trying to hook up a checkbox to my View, but as soon as I tick it, it stays checked, even when I click it again?

Here's part of the View:

```
views.PaginatedView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click input.completedEnquiries': 'filterCompletedEnquiries'
    },
    filterCompletedEnquiries: function (e) {
        return e.currentTarget.checked;
    }
});
```

Heres the template:

```
<label>Show Completed: <input type="checkbox" class="completedEnquiries" /></label>
```

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong here?

### Edit

Here is a Jsfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/9cvVv/167/

Comment: Something else is happening due everything looks right for me. Can you reproduce the issue in a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9cvVv/167/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is returning `e.currentTarget.checked` from your event handler. Returning `true` or `false` from this handler will check or uncheck the box for you

```
 filterCompletedEnquiries: function(e) {
        //return e.currentTarget.checked;
    },
```

comment out that return statement, and it works fine. You can still grab the info, but don't return anything from the method.

```
 filterCompletedEnquiries: function(e) {
        var isChecked = e.currentTarget.checked;
        // do stuff here, based on it being checked or not
    },
```

### Edit

Here's an example, based on the conversation in the comments:

```
views.PaginatedView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click input.completedEnquiries': 'completedEnquiriesClicked'
    },

    // this is explicitly an event handler, and that's all it should be used for
    completedEnquiriesClicked: function(e){
      this.showCompletedEnquiries = e.currentTarget.checked;
    },

    doSomething Else: function (e) {
        // now that we need to know, we can just check that attribute
        if (this.showCompletedEnquiries){
          // do something here
        }
    }
});
```

This is just one of many options you have, for making this work the way you want.

Comment: But I'd like to return a value based on whether its checked or not as I will use that value in another function..

Comment: don't use the event handler for this. that's a bad idea, as you have already seen. store the data in a model and access the data from that model, in the other moethod

Comment: you can store it in an attribute on the view, or create a different method (not the event handler) to return the value. remember, it's just javascript. there's nothing special about this being a backbone view... write code to hold the variable or access it when needed. just don't use the event handler because you've already seen the problem that causes.

Comment: Thanks! I put an attribute inside my `initialize` function and it seems to work now!

Comment: that works :) i updated my answer to show another possibility. there's lots of options for making this work.